# How to format python string based on byte length?

Tags: python, formatting, ascii

I have a problem with formatting my python output when the output contains non-ascii characters. Take the following example:

```
>>> persons = [['Anton',12], ['Jürgen',16], ['Bernd', 18]]
>>> for i in persons:
...     print '{0:10} {1:3}'.format(i[0], i[1])
...
Anton       12
Jürgen     16
Bernd       18
```

Naturally, I want the output to be perfectly aligned for the second argument, i.e.,

```
Anton       12
Jürgen      16
Bernd       18
```

How can I achieve my desired output using the `.format()` method?

I suspect that my problem has something to do with the way in which the length of strings is computed, i.e., character length vs. byte length,

```
>>> len('Jürgen'.decode('utf-8'))
6
>>> len('Jürgen')
7
```

but I could not find out how to specify the correct string format in this case.

As I type the question here on Stack Overflow, I can even visually see that the string 'Anton' has a different color than 'Jürgen', meaning that the latter may not be recognized as a 'normal' string, but what should I do?

Comment: Ignore the colors you're seeing here. The parser is trying to syntax-highlight your output as if it were Python code. It's not significant.

Comment: Decode from UTF-8, format everything as Unicode strings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if you mean `print '{0:10} {1:3}'.format(i[0].decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8'), i[1])`, that still does not work ...

Comment: @klopps You're still not formatting as unicode.

Comment: @klopps your format string must be Unicode too; `u'{0:10}...'.format()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the strings using UTF-8 and format as Unicode:

```
>>> persons = [['Anton',12], ['Jürgen',16], ['Bernd', 18]]
>>> for i in persons:
...     print u'{0:10} {1:3}'.format(i[0].decode('utf-8'), i[1])
... 
Anton       12
Jürgen      16
Bernd       18
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your list like:

```
persons = [['Anton',12], [u'Jürgen',16], ['Bernd', 18]]
```